# What's the correct way of saying this?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I can't remember which tutorial it was.

or

> I can't remember which tutorial was.

Is the "it" necessary?

Comment: Yes, [a dummy subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) is necessary there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "it" is necessary. "I can't remember which tutorial it was." is a complex sentence. It has a main clause "I can't remember" and a subordinate clause "which tutorial it was". If we delete "it" here, then the subordinary clause is not complete.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the "it" is necessary.

Comment: While correct, this answer would be much better with some explanation.